# Wrapping Signature Text inside Rectangle

Tags: java, pdfbox, digital-signature

I am creating digital signatures using `PDFBox` for one of my use case. However, the appearance of the signature generated from the [samples](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateVisibleSignature2.java) is different as per my requirement. My desired signature appearance is:

1. Signature text should be fit & wrapped inside the signature field rectangle.
2. Signature text font size should be automatically changed as per size of rectangle.
3. New lines should be added automatically in text as per the size of rectangle.
4. Signature background image should also be fit inside rectangle and its width:height ratio should not change. It should also be at centre of the field.

Currently, I am trying to achieve these requirements by explicit calculations inside code. Is there any standard way provided by `PDFBox` to achieve them?

Sample Signature Image:
[image]

Comment: No there is no standard way to do this. You'll need to write code yourself. The TextToPDF source has code for wrapping, there's also a formatter class for the acroform fields but it's not public.

Comment: Inspiration for adaptive text font size might also come from that formatter class.

Comment: @mkl can you please elaborate how can I use this formatter class for the same? If possible, please share some example implementation.

Comment: The class in question is the `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PlainTextFormatter`. Further inspiration may come from its use in the `insertGeneratedAppearance` method of `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper` and from its `calculateFontSize` method for adaptive font sizes.